# Most common number in list from user input in for loop - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's the thing:

I want to print the most common number in a list from user input in a for loop.
The thing is that the most common number that is returned is from the last loop, not from other inputs in the loop.

How can I do so?
Here's what I tried:

```
import statistics
from statistics import mode

def num():
    def most_common(num):
        return (mode(num))

    grid = int(input('Number of grids: '))

    for i in range(grid):

        print('grid n°',i + 1)
        num = [int(input('1st number: ')), int(input('2nd number: ')), int(input('3rd number: '))]


    print(most_common(num))
```

Comment: if you need many values then you have to keep them on list. Or use `print()` inside `for`-loop

Comment: Hint: when are you calling most_common?

Comment: Which part are you struggling with, specifically? Why are you defining nested functions? You have variables and functions with the same name, that can’t be good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store each `num` you generate in a list. Here I've used `grid_nums`

```py
import statistics
from statistics import mode

def num():
    def most_common(num):
        return (mode(num))

    grid = int(input('Number of grids: '))

    grid_nums = []

    for i in range(grid):
        print('grid n°',i + 1)
        num = [int(input('1st number: ')), int(input('2nd number: ')), int(input('3rd number: '))]
        grid_nums += num


    print(most_common(grid_nums))
```

Comment: Thank you! That’s what I figured (At least i understood the problem and new how to fix it), I just didn’t know how to store each num :D